# Extract a list from tuples

Tags: python, tuples

I am looking to create a unique list (like set values) on the fly from tuple in python. Is there a way to do it.

```
ip_addrs_with_ports = [('192.168.1.1', '1234'),('192.168.1.1', '1235'),('192.168.1.3', '1236')]
```

I don't want to iterate over the list, to get the ip address values. Is there any way I can get a setof ip address directly , something like.

```
ip_addr = ['192.168.1.1','192.168.1.3']
```

Comment: "Extract" implies the thing you want already exists, just inside something else. That's not the case here: only the *elements* of the list you want exist (spread across multiple tuples), not the list itself.

Comment: Thanks , I should have corrected the statement , I am trying to extract the unique values

Comment: That wont for retrieving unique elements

Answer (score 1):

You can use a set comprehension like this:

```
ip_addrs_with_ports = [('192.168.1.1', '1234'),('192.168.1.1', '1235'),('192.168.1.3', '1236')]

s = {t[0] for t in ip_addrs_with_ports}
```

...which will give...

```
{'192.168.1.3', '192.168.1.1'}
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
ip_addrs_with_ports = [('192.168.1.1', '1234'),('192.168.1.1', '1235'),('192.168.1.3', '1236')]

lst = list(set(map(lambda e:e[0],ip_addrs_with_ports)))
print(lst) # ['192.168.1.3', '192.168.1.1']
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a dictionary to extract and deduplicate the IPs:

```
ip_addr = list(dict(ip_addrs_with_ports))
```